# SciPy being installed automatically

Tags: python, aws-lambda, scipy, aws-amplify

So I have the following code:

```
import os
import io
import boto3
import json
import sagemaker
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import io
from sagemaker.amazon.record_pb2 import Record
import mxnet as mx
import base64

def handler(event, context):
```

The following Pipfile

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
boto3="*"
sagemaker="*"
image="*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

Now I'm trying to deploy this on AWS Lambda - the problem I'm having is somehow SciPy is ending up in the install bundle when I haven't installed it - I thought Numpy and SciPy were two different packages and can't figure out where it's coming from?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cos it's requirement in `sagemaker` see [setup.py](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/setup.py)

```py
# See setup.py from line 35 
# Declare minimal set for installation
required_packages = [
    "boto3>=1.13.6",
    "numpy>=1.9.0",
    "protobuf>=3.1",
    "scipy>=0.19.0",
    "protobuf3-to-dict>=0.1.5",
    "smdebug-rulesconfig==0.1.4",
    "importlib-metadata>=1.4.0",
    "packaging>=20.0",
]
```

Comment: Ahh thanks, silly me, marked as correct - new to python you see didn't think to look there :-)

Comment: No problems. It still happens to everyone. Keep in mind that there are some limitiation for disk size in AWS lambda. Finally consider to upvote too ;)

Comment: Yeah so that's what I'm fighting with now, actually looks like I'll need to dump sagemaker and call the endpoint directly(after signing the request)

Comment: Orrr, just nick sagemaker.amazon.record_pb2 from sagemaker since I only needed the ability to read the recordio stuff, make my own module from it, ditch sagemaker, voila.